# Why the next short in memory has the value of another variable?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the main method I have the following code:

```
int main (void)
{
    unsigned short array[3];
    *array = 65535;
    *(array + 1) = 12453;
    *(array + 2) = 45055;

    int bitposition = 12;

    int bitsperSample = 8;

    unsigned short * pointer_array = & array[0];
    unsigned short result = readSample(pointer_array, bitposition, bitsperSample);


}
```

My intention was to create a 3 element short array in which I can store 3 shorts in order to read them inside the function  readSample. The function is the following an the code inside is intended to read two shorts from the previously declared array :

```
unsigned short readSample( unsigned short * track, int bitpos, int bitsPerSample )
    {
    int res = 1;
    int short_to_read = bitpos / 16; 

    int pos_bit_in_the_short = bitpos % 16; // local position of the bit inside the short_to_read  

    unsigned short found = *(track + short_to_read);
    unsigned short * pointer_to_found  = & found;
    unsigned short copy_found = * pointer_to_found;
    printf("first short to read is %d \n", copy_found);

    unsigned short second_short_to_read = * (pointer_to_found + 1);
    printf("second short to read is %d \n", second_short_to_read);


    return res;
}
```

I expected the program to print:

```
first short to read is 65535
second short to read is 12453
```

But the program outputs:

```
first short to read is 65535
second short to read is 12
```

which is wrong, as the second short to read is taking the value of pos_bit_in_the_short = bitpos % 16, and I don't know why.

I also tried printing the hexadecimal addresses of the shorts to read and see if it accessing other part of memory, bit now, the second short is 2 bytes after the first one, as expected by the way I declared the array in the main method. The addresses were:

```
0xbfc120f2 for the first short and 
0xbfc120f4 for the second short.
```

Any one might have an idea why that happens?

Comment: You copy the first array element to `found`, create a pointer to `found` and then expect this pointer to index `found` like the array you copied the data from. But `found` is not an array.

Comment: `unsigned short found = *(track + short_to_read);` already copies the `short` out of your array. `unsigned short * pointer_to_found  = & found;` points to the copy, not the element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
unsigned short found = *(track + short_to_read);
unsigned short * pointer_to_found  = & found;
```

`found` is a local variable (in `readSample`) and the following logic uses it as if it were an array — which it is not.